# Pandas Filterting Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset from Bing. And this dataset contains state and county-level information. I am trying to create two different datasets, one for the county level and one for the state level.

How do I create an only-state level data frame. Here is a picture of what the dataset looks like:

[image]

The counties dataframe worked with this code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("COVID19-DATA-WITHSTATES.csv")

only_counties = df[df['AdminRegion2'].str.contains("", na = True)]
```

It didn't work for the state level with this code:

```
only_states = df[df['AdminRegion2' != ""]]
```

EDIT: This is the code that worked

```
only_states = usa_only[lambda x: ~pd.notnull(x['AdminRegion2']) & (usa_only["AdminRegion1"].str.contains("", na = False))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for only states, that worked.

```
only_states = usa_only[lambda x: ~pd.notnull(x['AdminRegion2']) & (usa_only["AdminRegion1"].str.contains("", na = False))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it with lambda expression:

```
only_states = df[lambda x: ~pd.isnull(x['AdminRegion2'])]
```

For the second question the above solution works as well:

```
df[lambda x: x['date'] == "date"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you explain what the lambda expression is and what it does? And also the code above? Just so I can learn?

Comment: It's a way to write a function without writing it explicitly. Here you are using lambda to create a series of true and false. first one checks a panda series to see if it is not null and when you use it with df it filters rows that the value of adminregion2 is not null for them.

Comment: Got it, also, if this was a worldwide dataset and I only wanted United States would this expression work? Because I tried it and it still shows all the countries.                                                                                                  df = pd.read_csv("Bing-COVID19-Data.csv")

usa_only = df[df["Country_Region"].str.contains("United States")]

Comment: Yes you can write :
usa_only = df[lambda x: x['Country_Region'].str.contains("United States")]